# How can you convert html inputs to js prompts?

Tags: javascript, html, bots

I'm making a kahoot bot bookmarklet and i can't figure out how to convert the inputs in this code to js prompts.

I tried setting the id as gameId to a prompt, but it did not seem to work.

```html
<form id="setgid" class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Set Game ID (Current Game ID: <span id="gameid">unset</span>)</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Game ID" name="gameid">
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Set Game ID</button>
<small>If you're having issues with this hack, please join the <a href="https://mem.rip/discord/mem">discord</a></small>
</form>
```

```
$("#setgid").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var gameId = Number(this.gameid.value);
  if (!isNaN(gameId)) {
    sendPacket(hackop.CHKGAME, i32s(gameId));
  } else {
    alert("Invalid game pin!");
  }
});
```

Here is the pen if you need it
https://codepen.io/moviecon/pen/eowMvQ

When I set a prompt I expected it to set the gameid, but it did not do any thing.

Comment: The `submit` event will only submit form data. Data returned from a `prompt()` is not form data and won't be submitted. You'd have to [set up your form data manually](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) based on the returned values from the `prompt()`..

Comment: explain in English please i am new developer

Comment: can i change the rest of my code in some way so it  can be used with prompts.

Comment: You're asking a coding question, but you don't want an answer that explains the code? You're not going to get very far with that approach.

Comment: sorry scott  i'm just a nine year old

Comment: This can be done, but not with just a few code changes.